# How to import an svg based on the current user role in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

How to import a svg on based on the user role if its admin or users.

cause right now my code is like this:

***layout.ts***

```
<div class="layout-body h-100 ">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="svgBuilding"></ng-container>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" class="h-100 w-100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1035.8 534.8"
    style="enable-background:new 0 0 1035.8 534.8;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
      g.building {
        fill: #FFFFFF;
      }

      g.building:hover {
        fill: #e2e2e2 !important;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .bldg-name {
        fill: #242323;
        stroke: #242323;
        stroke-width: .5;
      }

      .st1,
      .st2,
      .text {
        fill: #909090;
      }

      .st3 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 1.68;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st4 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 0.48;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st5 {
        font-family: 'CordiaNew';
      }

      .st6 {
        font-size: 3.141px;
        fill: #0000FF;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st7 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st8 {
        font-size: 5.4622px;
      }

      .st9 {
        font-family: 'AngsanaNew-Bold';
      }

      .st10 {
        font-size: 33.0262px;
      }

      .st11 {
        fill: #FFFE00;
      }

      .st12 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #F8D731;
        stroke-width: 0.48;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st13 {
        fill: #00FFFF;
        stroke: #DDA56E;
        stroke-width: 0.48;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }

      .st14 {
        fill: #00FFFF;
      }

    </style>
    <g id="building_a" class="building" (click)="openBuilding('BLDGA')">
      <path class="st0" d="M306.3,171.4v62.7H166.1v-1.8c-0.7,0-1.7,0.8-2,1.1v0.8H114c0.4,0.9,0.6,1.9-0.1,1.8c-1-0.2-1.3-1.2-1.3-1.8
        h-10.3v-62.7h23.9v-0.1h43.1v0.1h14.4v-7.7h46.7v7.7h75.9V171.4z" />
      <foreignObject x="240" y="170" width="75px" height="50px" style="position:relative;">
        <xhtml:div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <div *ngIf="count('BLDGA')">
            <div class="mechanic">
              <nz-badge [nzCount]="mechCount('BLDGA') || 0">
                <img src="./assets/images/room/room.png" width="45px" height="35px" />
              </nz-badge>
            </div>
          </div>
        </xhtml:div>
      </foreignObject>
     .....
    ....
    ...
    ..
    </svg>
```

and I have more svg. what I'm trying to do now is to less the code from the file `layout.ts`
by calling the svg file.

for example this svg is for admin only.

this svg is for advisor only.

this svg is for students only.

svg1 - admin
svg2 - advisor
svg3 - student

Comment: A svg it's only an image, you can has differents .svg in your assets folder and use <img src="...">

Comment: @Eliseo but I have a function and condition.

Comment: I put in the way of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we has differents .svg, we can do some like

```
<img [src]="role=='admin'?'assets/svg1.svg':
            role=='advisor'?'assets/svg2.svg':
            'assets/svg3.svg'">
```

Or create an auxiliar variable

```
images={
  admin:'assets/svg1.svg',
  advisor:'assets/svg2.svg',
  student:'assets/svg3.svg'
}
//and use
    <img [src]="images[role]'">
```

Comment: How'bout for example instead of svg. it will based on the html file?

Comment: are you asking about NgSwitchCase? https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch

Comment: what I mean example ```html = { admin: 'html/room1.html' }``` and then?

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding. You can not import a html in Angular, of course you can use [innerHTML]="variable" and this variable to be an html text. But to get the value you need use httpClient.get(). why not use differents components?